# Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly executing maven

Tags: java, maven, java-home

I installed java and set the path environment and when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` in the terminal I get the following output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

I Also installed `apache-maven` and changed `environment` file and now it looks like this:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java"
M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.5
M2=$M2_HOME/bin
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

But when I execute `mvn --version` I get a warning:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java/bin/java
```

Can not find out why it repeats in the end `/bin/java/bin/java`

Comment: One can use [sdkman](http://sdkman.io) to manage java and maven tool with ease.

Comment: In my case, the problem was that JAVA_HOME was defined in the $HOME/.mavenrc and it was pointing to a wrong path. I was able to find out the issue by adding some echo $JAVA_HOME lines to /usr/local/bin/mvn script and running mvn -v

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Assuming you use bash shell and installed Java with the Oracle installer, you could add the following to your `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

This would pick the correct `JAVA_HOME` as defined by the Oracle installer and will set it first in your `$PATH` making sure it is found.

Also, you don't need to change it later when updating Java.

**EDIT**

As per the comments:

**Making it persistent after a reboot**

Just add those lines in the shell configuration file. (Assuming it's `bash`)

Ex: `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or `.profile` (for ubuntu)

**Using a custom Java installation**

Set `JAVA_HOME` to the root folder of the custom Java installation path without the `$()`.

Ex: `JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk`

Comment: What if I want to make this persistent between launches?

Comment: Worth noting that for ubuntu, you should use .profile instead of .bash_profile according to http://askubuntu.com/questions/824829/creating-and-configuring-bash-profile

Comment: What if I want to use java from a share rather than the system java

Comment: Just updated the answer as per the comments. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Just for curiosity, why "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk" works but "JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" doesn't for custom Java installation?

Answer (score 24):

JAVA_HOME should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/`.

Comment: Right, you need to remove the trailing "/bin/java" from your path .. meaning:  JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/"

Answer (score 22):

We open a terminal and look for the location of java:

```
manuel@zonademanel:~ → whereis java
```

> java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java
>   /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

What we are looking for is /usr/bin/java continue on the command line to find the absolute path , as this is only a symbolic link.

```
manuel@zonademanel:~ → ls -lah /usr/bin/java
```

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 may 19  2015 /usr/bin/java ->
>   /etc/alternatives/java

```
manuel@zonademanel:~ → ls -lah /etc/alternatives/java
```

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 dic  7 11:52 /etc/alternatives/java ->
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java

I modified my **/etc/environment** file with the following values

> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:**/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin**"
>   JAVA_HOME="**/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre**"

If I do not want to relogin I can reload the changes with:

```
source /etc/environment
```

​​And run **mvn -version** correctly

```
manuel@zonademanel:~ → mvn -version
```

> Apache Maven 3.0.5
>   Maven home: /usr/share/maven
>   Java version: 1.8.0_77, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
>   Default locale: es_MX, platform encoding: UTF-8
>   OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-70-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Answer (score 11):

`$JAVA_HOME` should be the directory where java was installed, not one of its parts:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Answer (score 9):

You might get this error due to couple of reasons. To fix this quickly please follow below steps,

First find the java location. To get a list of your installed Java platforms, run the following command from the terminal:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Now set JAVA_HOME and PATH,

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=<java_home>

$ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

Create the symlink

```
$ sudo ln -s <java_home>/jre <java_symlink_path>
```

When we take your case as a example :

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

Above command will create the symlink location where the system is trying to find in your issue.

Finally do the

```
$ mvn --version
```

Comment: absolute legend

Answer (score 6):

You should set as it is export `JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31` and run with `sudo` it will execute as shown below.

**Example**

```
sudo mvn -v
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.10, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-70-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: This what worked for me on debian! ( manual installation of JDK )

Comment: `sudo` solved my problem. My `JAVA_HOME` was correct, but I was seeing the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, in a development mode, you should use JDK instead of the JRE.
Secondly, the JAVA_HOME is where you install Java and where all the others frameworks will search for what they need (JRE,javac,...)

So if you set

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java

when you run a "mvn" command, Maven will try to access to the java by adding /bin/java, thinking that the JAVA_HOME is in the root directory of Java installation.

But setting

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/

Maven will access add bin/java then it will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

This solution work for me...
just type 
`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH` in the terminal
then run `mvn -version`
it will show the same error but with a log like this

```
which: no javac in (/jre/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin)
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T22:59:23+05:30)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

now copy the `Java home` path i.e. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64/jre` in my case.

now type,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64/jre
```

and the error gets resolve.
NOTE: paste your own path which is shown by your machine in mvn log at export JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 2):

You must take the whole directory where java is installed, in my case:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because of the reason mentioned below :

If you see the mvn script: The code fails here ---

Steps for debugging and fixing:

Step 1: Open the mvn script /Users/Username/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn
(Open with the less command like: less /Users/Username/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn)

Step 2: Find out the below code in the script:

```
  if [ -z "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME"  ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
      # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
  else
    JAVACMD="`which java`"
  fi
fi

if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  echo "Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly."
  echo "  We cannot execute $JAVACMD"
  exit 1
fi
```

Step3: It is happening because `JAVACMD` variable was not set. So it displays the error.

Note: To Fix it

```
export JAVACMD=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Key: If you want it to be permanent 
open emacs .profile

post the commands 
and press Ctrl-x Ctrl-c ( save-buffers-kill-terminal ).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mac-OS , `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home` need to be changed to `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` . 
Steps to do this :

```
 $ vim .bash_profile

 export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

 $ source .bash_profile
```

where `/usr/libexec/java_home` is the path of your jvm

Answer (score 1):

Use these two commands (for Java 8):

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-8-oracle
java -XshowSettings 2>&1 | grep -e 'java.home' | awk '{print "JAVA_HOME="$3}' | sed "s/\/jre//g" >> /etc/environment
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was in vscode.

I use windows and installed Ubuntu on my computer, so vscode terminal uses the Ubuntu. I just go to settings.json and change to cmd.exe again

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue but with open jdk and none of the answers here helped. The trouble was that the mvn script was appending /bin/java at the end of JAVA home while trying to run java commands.

The solution for me was to manually edit the /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn script (your own script might be installed differently; just run which mvn) and change

```
   if [ -z "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME"  ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
      # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" 
    fi
  else
    JAVACMD="`which java`"
  fi
 fi
```

To

```
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME"  ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
      # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else 
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME"
    fi
  else
    JAVACMD="`which java`"
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

add in .bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

and then

source .bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and it was not getting resolved even after editing and sourcing the .bash_profile, .bashrc file. I got it resolved by editing the maven.sh file directly.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export M2=/opt/maven/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME:$M2HOME:$M2
```

and then sourcing the file

```
source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

For those who didnt get they issue resolved with other answers, give this a try as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the java installation path, installations usually create a symlink.
Using this symlink that doesn't change regardless of the version, you can paste this line into your .bashrc:

```bash
# .bashrc
export JAVA_HOME="$(realpath /etc/alternatives/java | sed -E 's/(.*)((\/[^/]+){2,})/\1/g')"
```

The realpath function returns the absolute path of the symlink.
Then the sed function does a replace with regex, removing two parts from the end.

**I haven't tested what I'm going to say next, it's a guess...**
It can be useful if you use several versions, because if you change the version with `sudo update-alternatives --config java`, the reference already points to the current version, **IF the symlink is changed automatically**.