# mvn -version error: We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java

Tags: java, macos, maven, bash

======
EDIT 2:

I used the same code as mentioned below in edit 1, my error apparently was not in the code itself but rather due to source ~/.bash_profile not updating my file as expected. I think, however (thank you @eckes) please see the maven bug:( BTW: jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5686 –  eckes 39 secs ago)

EDIT 1: this is not a duplicate of: [What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx)

I have tried all of the solutions mentioned in the above post, and they do not work for me. My issue is that I am doing one of the solutions listed there here (I tried the others). I am still getting the error.

I'm currently trying as per above instructions:

```
  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

and getting:

```
  source ~/.bash_profile
  mvn -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java
```

=======
I installed the latest java jdk from oracle

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

I installed Xcode to install maven however recent documentation states that I may use brew ([Maven Install on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826881/maven-install-on-mac-os-x))

I installed maven with:

```
//install brew
brew doctor
brew install maven
```

I then tried:

```
mvn -version
     Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
```

I found: http://hathaway.cc/post/69201163472/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac

However this is based on java 7 I believe. But it seemed likely to be a fix.

There is no bash_profile on the new mac (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26928/no-bash-profile-in-os-x-lion)

So I created and edited my bash_profile with:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
vim ~/.bash_profile
//and added the line export JAVA_HOME=(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

My problem is that even with this fix I am still getting the following error:

```
 mvn -version
      Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
      We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java
```

I checked however that within my file system java_home is where the file lies. There is no  "/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java" in my file system as maven error'ed out on.

Has anyone else encountered this with the new java 8, and brew installed maven? I'm using a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) running Yosemite. I've installed a setup like this before but never encountered this issue.

**Note:

I found this: http://www.mkyong.com/java/maven-java_home-is-not-defined-correctly-on-mac-osx/

Which I thought would definitely be my fix. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe the difference is the parenthesis.

Ex:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
```

vs

```
 export JAVA_HOME=(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

However my error has not been fixed. (Also just in case anyone asks I source(ed) it before rerunning.) It did however change my error. It removed the additional /bin/java.

```
 mvn -version
      Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
      We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java
```

JAVA_HOME:

```
 echo $JAVA_HOME
      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home
```

**note i tried the $() syntax and this did not fix the problem.

Comment: Did you insert the spaces in `export JAVA_HOME = /usr/libexec/java_home`? Can you open a Terminal window and do `echo $JAVA_HOME`, and tell us the result?

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/libexec/java_home. There are no spaces. it's JAVA_HOME=(/usr/.../java_home)

Comment: I guess the backtick shell syntax (replacing the value with the output of the command) was lost in your sources. The $() is the alternative syntax: `JAVA_HOME=\`java_home\``

Comment: @eckes wait sorry could you explain that? I switched it to $() and it still isn't working correctly?

Comment: both is correct. You just need to make sure you run the command in your current session and export it. Your error message shows that mvn stil lsees the old value. But for a begin, just set it to a fixed string and try it. if this does not work you have another problem (for example the mvn script is modified or similar).

Comment: @eckes I run source ~/.bash_profile, and then I try mvn -version and I am still getting : JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java. This is with the correct $() syntax

Comment: Then check if ~/.mavenrc or /etc/mavenrc overwrites the variable. You can also use `MAVEN_SKIP_RC=true mvn -v` (one line) to verify it is one of those files.

Comment: I ran the line : MAVEN_SKIP_RC=true mvn -v
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java   Also ~/.mavenrc does not yet exist as a file

Comment: Then you can run `bash -x mvn` - it will print a lot of stuff (one line starting with + for every command) but you should see how JAVA_HOME gets assigned with a wrong value.

Comment: ...
+ '[' -x /usr/libexec/java_home/jre/sh/java ']'
+ JAVACMD=/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java
+ '[' '!' -x /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java ']'
+ echo 'Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.'
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
+ echo '  We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java'
  We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java
+ exit 1

Comment: I'll go with the benefit of the doubt here.  It reads like the solution in the duplicate would work for you.  Double-check your permissions; make sure that you can actually execute the binary.

Comment: actually there is a bug in the mvn script, it needs to use $() as well. however it should not reach that line if JAVA_HOME was correctly set before. Anyway, change the `JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home` in that script into $() version and it should work

Comment: @Makoto hey, thanks for the benefit of the doubt. I read the solution on the other page. It isn't working for me. It's a new computer hmm maybe ill check permissions. Weird

Comment: @eckes hmm ok wait my bash_profile is: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) which is correct yes? You want me to change which script to $() format?

Comment: @eckes OH, interesting. So I was running source ~/.bash_profile because I thought that that would refresh the file / location. I opened another window and it started running. The error I believe I was having was that source... was not update the file as I expected. A new window runs fine. Thank you so much for the help. My *solution* was creating a new terminal page. Any reasons why source .... doesn't work?

Comment: @Makoto you're correct the code required is a duplicate. I'm unsure of why I was having the above issue of source ~/.bash_profile not updating and allowing the file to run. I had to restart open terminal. Feel free to remove. Sorry!

Comment: BTW: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5686

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You missed on one little thing, I believe:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
                 ⬆︎
          This dollar sign
```

This tells the shell "The value of this expression is the output from executing the following command (`/usr/libexec/java_home)`)"

Running the command gives the proper java home for the mac (if you have a single JDK installed), and that value is placed in JAVA_HOME. Without the dollar sign, it just puts the name of the command there.

Comment: Oh, awesome. I fixed that. I now get echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home, however maven still isn't running: mvn -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java

Comment: Did you export it? or did you actually logged in again (or sources .bashrc).

Comment: Are you running mvn in a different tab or terminal window?

Comment: I owe you a box of candy.

Answer (score 3):

I write on .bash_profile file these lines and then work for me.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=/Users/(YOUR USER)/Documents/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

Note: work on macOS Sierra (10.12.6)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44564303/5005676
If you see the mvn script: The code fails here ---

Steps for debugging and fixing:

Step 1: Open the mvn script /Users/Username/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn (Open with the less command like: less /Users/Username/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn)

Step 2: Find out the below code in the script:

```
  if [ -z "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME"  ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
      # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
  else
    JAVACMD="`which java`"
  fi
fi

if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  echo "Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly."
  echo "  We cannot execute $JAVACMD"
  exit 1
fi
```

Step3: It is happening because JAVACMD variable was not set. So it displays the error.

Note: To Fix it

```
export JAVACMD=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Key: If you want it to be permanent open emacs .profile

post the commands and press Ctrl-x Ctrl-c ( save-buffers-kill-terminal ).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had two entries for JAVA_HOME in my ~/.bash_profile and the last one was taking precedence. I just deleted the one which was wrong and it worked.