# mvn command not working on mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, maven

I have performed all the necessary steps like the following after referring other Stack overflow threads and online resources for installing / configuring maven. Here is what I did :

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9

export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
```

My Java Home variable is also, set, as shown below:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60/Contents/Home

export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

Inspite of doing all of the above, when I run `mvn --version`, I get `Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60/Contents/Home/bin/java`.

PATH Output is as follows :

```
 echo $PATH
/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't put `M2` on your `PATH`.

Comment: @chrylis You mean, I should do `export $PATH=M2` ?

Comment: strange thing is that `sudo mvn --version` worked for me.

Comment: This works for me, good luck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319495/error-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly-executing-maven

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`export PATH=$M2:$PATH` should be `export PATH=$M2/bin:$PATH` or `export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Also JAVA_HOME should be something like this

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60`

then

`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

That's all.

All in one

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I would also like to add as a side note that you can make your life a lot easier if you choose to use a package manager that can do most of the manual work for you in terms of installing and placing things in path. If you have some time - have a look on brew and brew cask . See [here](http://javapapo.blogspot.gr/2015/08/brew-and-brew-cask-package-manager-for.html) or [here](http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Homebrew/Cask.html)

Comment: @11thdimension Thanks for the answer and comment javapapo. My path variable is `echo $PATH
/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin` I made the changes in `JAVA_HOME` variable as suggested. Still, I need to run `sudo mvn --version` to make sure that maven is running properly. If I just run `mvn --version` without `sudo`, I get the error `Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java
`

Comment: Could anyone explain me why it throws `JAVA_HOME` error in spite of setting the path correctly?

Comment: Are you able to use Java commad in the terminal ? If you are able to use it, then try to run `which java`, which will give you the correct path to java executable. Post the output if you can find the path.

Comment: @11thdimension When I ran the following command on the terminal:`ls -l `which java``, I got the following :`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Jun 25  2015 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`

Comment: what is the content of 
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60/Contents/Home` directory ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem and resolved it by getting the JAVA_HOME path by executing the following command:
**/usr/libexec/java_home -version**

output:
java_home: option `-version' requires an argument
**/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home**

Copy and paste this as value to JAVA_HOME and try again.
It should work.