# How to set [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows] [environment variables] from [windows path]?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Try to use [samza.apache.org/startup/hello-samza/0.7.0/](http://samza.apache.org/startup/hello-samza/0.7.0/) with Bash On Windows

it will run

```
bin/grid bootstrap
```

where the flowing code

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  if [ -x /usr/libexec/java_home ]; then
    export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
  else
    echo "JAVA_HOME not set. Exiting."
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

give an error

```
JAVA_HOME not set. Exiting.
```

on CMD when i run

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

i got

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\
```

I want to import the path data to bash

[image]

Comment: Have you installed Java on the Bash shell directly?  It won't recognize the path `C:\...`.  To Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, the path would be `/mnt/c/...`  What happens when you run `echo $JAVA_HOME` in the bash shell?

Comment: how to  install Java on the Bash shell directly ? echo $JAVA_HOME gives a blank line

Comment: If you want to install the JDK for Ubuntu -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478741/installing-oracle-jdk-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Comment: Looks like a way to share variables, which includes path conversions was introduced in Insider Build 17063: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/22/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would try `export JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_102"` to set the JAVA_HOME variable in the bash shell.

**Update (response to your edit):**

I wouldn't recommend trying to automatically import your Windows paths to Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, because the paths have to be converted to be understood by the bash shell (`\` to `/`, `C:\` to `mnt/c/` and so on), and because not all of the tools you're probably going to reference will work on both Windows and Linux.  Instead, install what you need on the Bash shell using [`apt-get`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) (you don't need to use `sudo` because BUW loads in a root shell).  Java is probably fine to reference as above, but most things you'll want installed separately on Ubuntu.

Comment: worked! but now it asking for git path? my main question:  is there a way to set Path variable for bash From window Path automatically on bash startup

Comment: You may need to install git on the bash shell if you haven't already.  (`apt-get update` then `apt-get git`)  Add the variables to your `~/.bashrc` file (syntax is the same) - .  Then, either restart the shell, or type `source ~/.bashrc` to reload the environment variables.

Comment: apt-get will install a new instanse  , I have "/mnt/c//Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe" and"C:\Users\mohamad\.bashrc" like this https://gist.github.com/Elrashid/a16f74449c108d2336aec21abe80fa59 how to add it ?

Comment: .exe files don't run on Linux.  I'm recommending that you install git separately on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.  See my edit above.

Comment: Since June 2017, the [windows executables can be invoked from the Bash on Ubuntu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/interop) and you can invoke bash from command line.. However, the windows executables will use the windows environment variables and configuration.

Comment: wslpath is your (new) friend in Wsl2, so no reason to do the path importing to Wsl from Win manual.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick solution, I created a powershell script that would

1. Take all windows environment variables
2. Change the path separator to `/`
3. Change `C:` to `/mnt/c`
4. Output `export` commands one line per environment variable

   ```
   Get-ChildItem Env: | % {"export $($_.Name)=`"$($_.Value.Replace('\', '/').Replace('C:', '/mnt/c'))`""}
   ```

Now, all you need to do is run this script in Powershell, copy the output and paste it in WSL/Ubuntu on Windows to populate the environment variables. You could also put all these commands in a `.sh` file and execute it using bash.

It is a crude solution, but this worked for me. I'm open to suggestions on improving this.

Answer (score 1):

My path environment variable seems to already have my windows paths there. But you can run windows programs from Ubuntu on Windows. So you can get environment variables or whatever you like.

```
export PATH=$PATH:`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe -/C "echo %PATH%"`
```

It isn't recommended to use Cygwin (licensing, registry corruption, etc). But below should work. run is documented to run windows programs from the bash shell it gives you.

```
export PATH=$PATH:`run /mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe -/C "echo %PATH%"`
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest answer since it doesn't require PowerShell. I would add that in Windows command line, `%PATH%` is the correct variable reference, not `$PATH` (which is the Linux variable reference).

Comment: you might need to append `| sed -e 's/;/:/g'` or other string processing to replace semicolons with colons. If there is a better suggestion then sed (zsh compatible maybe?), leave a comment.

Comment: @yuyu5 this does not work in a windows cmd, do not know why you think this is for a cmd.

Comment: Think about wslpath to convert the paths. Otherwise, your solution is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This one is working for me, by setting **WSLENV** in the System variables environment.

System variables
[image]

Answer (score 0):

export [variable-name]='any-path' for current shell session

e.g.

```
export VSCode='C:/Program Files/....'
echo $VSCODE
```